# Send an attachment using Python script

Tags: python, gmail, mime, smtplib

I used following python script to send an attachment through gmail. But it can be used for send an attachment which is saved in the same folder python script is saved. I want to send an attachment which is saved in different folder. How can I do it by modifing this script? Thank you.

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import Encoders
import os
import datetime


smtpUser = ' '
smtpPass = ' '

toAdd = ' '
fromAdd = smtpUser

today = datetime.date.today()

subject  = 'Data File 01 %s' % today.strftime('%Y %b %d')
header = 'To :' + toAdd + '\n' + 'From : ' + fromAdd + '\n' + 'Subject : ' + subject + '\n'
body = 'This is a data file on %s' % today.strftime('%Y %b %d')

attach = 'Data on %s.csv' % today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print header


def sendMail(to, subject, text, files=[]):
    assert type(to)==list
    assert type(files)==list

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = smtpUser
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )

    for file in files:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload( open(file,"rb").read() )
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"'
                       % os.path.basename(file))
        msg.attach(part)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
    server.login(smtpUser,smtpPass)
    server.sendmail(smtpUser, to, msg.as_string())

    print 'Done'

    server.quit()


sendMail( [toAdd], subject, body, [attach] )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fourth parameter of `sendMail` is a list of filenames, so you can do e.g.:

```
sendMail(["name@domain.com"], 
         "Subject", 
         "Dear sir..", 
         ["subdir/file1.zip", "subdirfile.zip"] )
```

whereas `subdir/file1.zip` is relative to the path where you call the script. If you want to refer to a file somewhere completely else use `/path/to/my/file1.zip`, e.g. `/home/user/file1.zip`

Comment: The question asks about sending files outside of the script's working directory. Consider including absolute paths in your answer.

Comment: I took "different folder" as a subdir, but of course it could be somewhere completely else as well, thanks for the hint